# issue in toran proxy after update to v1.4.4 with private repositories

Tags: composer-php, toran-proxy

After update toran-proxy to v1.4.4, I have an issue with private repositories.

The following message appeared when updating my private repository :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all,

I find the solved it by adding the username of my bitbucket account to the added linked

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
```